# Selection disappears when new window opens

Tags: javascript, html, select

I am currently working on a project and I am stuck. As per client requirements a small modification was made to an existing form.

Imagine the HTML page as follows:

- I have added a new form element named Business Type and there are 10 options in that.
- The user needs to select an option or multiple options and submit and the data would get stored in the database. The data is also getting stored in the database. I have checked that.
- There is also a button within the form which opens up a small window to choose a few options. When this window opens up, the selection made in Business Type (in the form) disappears. How to prevent this from happening?

I am trying to use sessions. But is there a better and easier way to accomplish this? I want to retain the multiple selections that are made.

Comment: Can you show us your code? Is it not simply a matter of getting the stored selections out of the database and use them to set the markup of the popup accordingly?

Comment: cant suggest until u tell us how do u open the child windown and populate it and how the communication between child and parent window is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This can all be done client-side. Basically, you create a form with all of the questions that you want to ask and then use JavaScript to display extra questions. If the user doesn't click the button to open the extra questions, they just maintain their empty values. If they do open the extra questions, the will pop up on the page and the user will fill in the inputs. Once they are finished with those questions, you simply hide them but they still hold the values that the user set.

So put the optional fields in a hidden div in the form, and then display that div when the button is clicked.

```
<form ...>
... required inputs
...
...
<a href="#" id="show-optional-inputs">Ask more questions</a>
<div id="optional-inputs" style="display: none;">
    <input ... />
    <input ... />
    <a href="#" id="save-optional-inputs">'Save' optional questions</a>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

Then, give the `#optional-inputs` some CSS (or you can style it however you like):

```
#optional-input {
   left: ...px;
   position: absolute;
   top: ...px;
   width: ...px;
}
```

For the button/link that opens the other questions, add some JavaScript/jQuery to open the div as an absolute positioned window.

```
$('#show-optional-inputs').click(function(e) {
    $('#optional-inputs').show();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This will get you mostly there. You would need to bind an event to trigger the optional questions box to save/close - which is actually just hiding the box and keeping the values that the user set in the form.